# Email Template Content Block Area - Overwrite CSS

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, css, html, content-builder

I am working on revamping email templates in Marketing Cloud for non-technical marketers to use. I am running into an issue/haven't found a solution for overwriting CSS in content areas that a user might apply. For instance, if I want to restrict a content area to a headline, I can restrict that area to text-only, but the user can go in and apply any font style they wanted to that headline in the content block creation process.

Is there a way to overwrite styling via CSS within the template to make sure the marketer can't create an off-brand email? I have tried applying a class to the div/slot and declaring it !important, but that doesnt seem to resolve the issue. What am I missing?

Thanks as always!